# finding the length of a form select element using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, select

i've tried several different variations of finding the length of a select element and nothing's working! i can't figure out why, since several websites list this is as the correct code.

here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    alert(document.getElementById("opentimes").options.length);
</script>
```

and here's the form:

```
<form action="eateries.php" method="POST" name="filters">
        <select name="opentimes" id="opentimes" onChange="document.forms.filters.submit();">
            <option value="now">Open Now</option>
            <option value="tonight">Open Tonight</option>
            <option value="late">Open Late</option>
            <option value="whenever">Open Whenever</option>
        </select>
.......
</form>
```

i know the alert is working because i've tested it with simple strings. i've tried variations like document.filters.opentimes.length and document.forms.filters.opentimes.length but nothing works!

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code is actually working, but I guess your code is executed before the DOM is loaded. Try this, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onload = function(){
        alert(document.getElementById("opentimes").options.length);
    };
</script>
```

All code which is wrapped in `window.onload = function(){ ... };` will be executed when the HTML-structure on the webpage is loaded. From that moment, you can use the `document.getElementById()` method.

Also, you can move your code down to the end of the document, but I wouldn't recommend that. It's ugly.

Comment: ahh yes, that was the issue! i actually had the alert in a function but pasted it that way for simplicity. i was calling the function before the select was built. changed the order and it works now. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Order of execution.  You're probably trying to access #opentimes before it exists in the DOM.

Try either putting your javascript *below* the `<select>` (in source order) or wrapping it in the body's load event.

2nd suggestion in action

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  onload = function()
  {
    alert(document.getElementById("opentimes").options.length);
  }
</script>
```

But be warned - you can often overwrite other "on load" functionality if other scripts are using it.